# Syntax error with IF statement in Python 3.0

Tags: python, syntax

I am teaching myself some Python and I have come across a problem which is probably plainly obvious, except that I can't see it and I need another pair of eyes.

I am making a small game I made into a gui program. 
I have this section of code, which when run gives me
"Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "", line 21, in 
Syntax Error:     if playguess == "A":: , line 2124"
 Line 21 being  if playguess == "A":

There may be a couple unrelated things wrong, but it's the IF statement that is baffling me right now.
I have imported the Tkinter module, I just copied the part that I thought was relevant.

```
def compare():
    R = Label(main, text = 'Yes you are right !')
    W = Label(main, text = "No, It's "+str(states[state])
    #if playerguess == str(states[state]):
    if playguess == "A":
       R.pack()
    else:
       W.pack()

#print ("Guess State Capitols")
state = choosestate()
main = Tk()
main.title("Guess State Capitols")
main.geometry('450x100+200+100')

Q = Label(main,text = 'What is the capitol of ' +state)
Q.pack()
playerguess = Entry(main)
playerguess.pack()
playguess = playerguess.get()



main.mainloop()
```

Comment: Could you elaborate on the problem you're having? Code snippets, the error in question?

Comment: Yes, there are hundreds of thousand of eyes just waiting here to help you out. Currently, they're all blind :-)

Comment: @pax maybe time for  psychicoverflow?

Comment: Sorry guys, I accidentally hit enter before meaning to. I'm stunned at the speed of response. I figured I'd fix it before anyone noticed.

Comment: And there are : in the right places (I think)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The line:

```
W = Label(main, text = "No, It's "+str(states[state])
```

Doesn't have a closing parentheses for the Label() class/function.

Therefore, the if statement is interpreted as being inside parentheses, which doesn't work.